# log10 inverse transformation: -10*log10(x)

Tags: r, logging, transformation, data-transform

I am trying to convert the -10*log10(x) to y but not sure with my code.

My code looks like:

```
y = 1/log(x) * -10
```

Can anyone confirm it?

Comment: Well, `log` returns the natural logarithm (see the online doc) and `1/log(x)` is the same as `log(-x)`, so I'd say you still have a way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly:

```
x <- 5
y <- -10 * log10(x)
# Inverse transformation
10^(-y/10)
#[1] 5
```